# How to update the user table with Ion Auth update

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

I am trying to implement a change email and change password function on my application, and after studying the documentation and questions on stack overflow, I still appear to be having trouble.

I have a view which passes the new email to be used, like so:

```
<?php echo form_open("change_email"); ?>
  <input name="changeemail" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="New Email">
  <button type="submit" class="submit AccountButton">Submit</button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

and my controller should be passing this data with the required id and multi-dimensional array to the update function like so:

```
public function change_email()
{
$userId = $this->ion_auth->get_user_id();
$newemail = $this->input->post('changeemail');
$data = array(
    'email' => $newemail,
);
$this->ion_auth->update($userId, $data);
}
```

After executing this function and not receiving any errors, upon checking the database there doesn't appear to be any changes.

Can anybody offer some help on this?

Comment: There is no db->where.

Comment: `$this->ion_auth->update($userId, $data);` is returning TRUE?

Comment: I've found the issue - the code is executing correctly and returning TRUE. however, for some reason after clicking the submit button, I am not being directed to /change_email for the code to actually execute. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Use the name of the controller in form_open ie `<?php echo form_open("controller/change_email"); ?>`

Comment: Yes, i corrected this in the application to no avail- I'm still not getting redirected

Comment: base_url is set in config.php? If you look at the source code generated for the <form>, is <form action=...> looking right?

Answer (score 0):

Try with a db where

```
public function change_email()

{
$userId = $this->ion_auth->get_user_id();
$newemail = $this->input->post('changeemail');
$data = array(
    'email' => $newemail,
);
$this->db->where('some_user_id_name', $userId);
$this->db->update('user_table_name', $data);
}
```

Comment: The function `ion_auth->update($userId, $data);` handles that internally.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember seeing get_user_id() method in the Ion_Auth library. You could do something like this:

```
$user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
$userId = $user->id;
$newemail = $this->input->post('changeemail');
$data = array(
    'email' => $newemail,
);
$this->ion_auth->update($userId, $data);
```

Hope this helped you.